# Impose more than one generic type constraint on a Scala type parameter

Tags: scala, generics, context-bound

I want to do the following stuff using Scala's context-bound pattern:

```
    class Polynomial[T: Ring] {
        def apply[X: Ring with Includes[T]](x: X): X = ...
        ...
    }
```

This is a polynomial class which requires the coefficients are elements in a `Ring T`. When applying this polynomial to a element (evaluation), the type of the parameter `x` is required to be a ring, and elements of type `T` can be implicitly cast to type `X`. for example `T = Double, X = SquareMatrix`.

How can I impose more than one type constraints to a generic type parameter in Scala?

Comment: why do you need context bound here? `Ring` is a typeclass?
maybe you need something like this: 
`def apply[X: Ring with Includes[T], T <% X](x: X): X = ...`
 view bound (<%) will check that T can be implicitly cast to X

Comment: @wedens yes. Ring is a typeclass designed to make Int, Double,... conform to it.

Comment: so, my solution should work in this case

Comment: What does the definition of `Includes` look like?

Comment: @sjrd trait Includes[A, B] {
  implicit def from(b: B): A
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that `[X: T]` syntax is not enough for imposing two generic type constraints. Using two implicit parameters solved this problem:

```
   def apply[X](x: X)(implicit ring: Ring[X], conv: Includes[X, T]): X = {
     var xi = ring.one
     var sum = ring.zero
     for (i <- 0 to degree) {
       sum += xi * conv.from(coef(i))
       xi *= x
     }
    return sum
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `[X: T]` syntax is simply syntactic sugar for requiring an implicit parameter of type `T[X]`. For example, `f` and `f2` below are identical:

```
 def f[T: X]
 def f2[T](implicit xt: X[T])
```

As for your code, if you explicitly write out the implicit parameter you will be able to express your constraints:

```
class Polynomial[T: Ring] {
    def apply[X](x: X)(implicit xt: Ring[X] with Includes[T]): X = ...
}
```

Note that you aren't imposing more than one constraint on either `X` or `T`, your constraint is simply too complex for the context-bound syntactic sugar. However, Scala does allow you to impose as many context-bounds on type parameters as you like, and you can combine them with upper- and lower-bounds as well:

```
def f[T >: List[Int] <: AnyRef : Ordering : List] = ???
```

Comment: I would like to have X conforming to Ring[X] and Includes[T].